# Multi class SVM classifier with HOG descriptor

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, svm

I created an SVM classifier with HOG (Histogram oriented Gradient) to detect a specific shape and it's working, I create positive images and negative images to use them in the *detectMultiScale* function.

I want to detect not only positive images, but also negative images and I can't find how to do that.

If i have for example two classes A and B I want to have 3 possible cases in an image not 1:

(i) just A 
(ii) just B 
(iii) neither A nor B(nothing).

Comment: `detectMultiScale` relates to *detection* with boosting, it is  different from classification with SVM. Could you please be more specific in your question ?

Comment: I have 2 classes lets say classe A and Classe B, if i use SVM + HOG i have to add positive and negative samples, and i can only detect positive, in my example A is the positive and B the negative, and i can only detect classe A, but me i want to detect both, Classe A and B in the same image.

Comment: SVM are natively binary classifiers (2 classes) thus it classifies "A" versus "non A". If you consider that "non A" is "B" thus, from the SVM point of view, any sample/image that is not classified as "A" is "B". The SVM returns a negative score for "B".

Comment: Maybe you should provide a [MCVE] to be clear

Comment: My code is very long, I will try to create a small code and add it later. In my problem I have a stream  video as input and then I want to search if Class A exist, or Class B exist, or neither class A nor class B exist (Nothing), that's what I am looking for to do

Comment: More than the code, you should edit your question to precise this point: can you have the 4 possible cases in an image: (i) just A (ii) just B (iii) both A and B (iv) neither A nor B. If so, you have a multilabel problem and you should have 2 classifier, one for A (versus "non A") and the other for "B" (versus "non B").

Comment: `I want to detect not only positive images but also negative images and I can't find how to do that.` If your image does not get classified as positive it **is** detected as negative in a binary classification

Comment: @xiawi I do not know what it's feasible in my case (SVM + HOG) to have 2 classifier, and I don't know how to do it, I have to train to same SVM with the 2 classifiers? or create 2 SVMs? and if I create 2 SVMs how to combine them the detect the two classes in the same image?

Comment: @TA Yes, but it detects Class A as Class A, and all the rest as Class B, me, I want the algorithm to detect Class A as Class A, Class B as Class B, And the rest as 'nothing detected'

Comment: Let post your (minimal !) code with one SVM and we'll propose you something for both classes...

Comment: I add a code and an explication here: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56643987/detectmultiscale-in-a-multi-classification-svm-hog-classifier-in-video-stream